# Ruby on rails does not create foreign keys on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

Is it normal that rails doesn't create the foreign keys on database? Or I'm doing something wrong?

I have these models:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

and their respective migrations:

```
class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :city, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Rails doesn't automatically add foreign keys, you have to specify it yourself in the migration like you have.

`t.references :city` is effectively the same as `t.integer :city_id`.

Are you saying that even though are specifying a foreign key, that you aren't seeing the results?

Comment: Exactly, even with this configuration the foreign keys are not created in the database.

Comment: Have you also remembered to assign the user to the city? Maybe paste your controller as well